# $S=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2\ |\ x^2-y=.3\}$ is connected/compact?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to know wether $$ S=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2: x^2-y=.3\}$$
is compact or connected or neither of them.

I know it is a parabola symmetric about $x$ axis having its vertex at $(0,-.3)$. So, I do not think it is connected nor is compact for the set is not bounded.
I want to verify if I am right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in seeing that it's not compact, because $S$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, it is connected. To see this, define a function $\langle id_\mathbb{R}, x^2-.3\rangle: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $\langle id_\mathbb{R}, x^2-.3\rangle(x) = (x,x^2-.3)$. Then, $\langle id_\mathbb{R}, x^2-.3\rangle$ is continuous and $\langle id_\mathbb{R}, x^2-.3\rangle[\Bbb{R}]=S$. Thus, $S$ is the continuous image of a connected set, hence connected.

Comment: I have confusion sir. Isnt it a parabola symentric about x-axis?

Is a circle in $R^2$ is connected.

Comment: If $(x,y) \in S$, then $x^2-y=.3$ so that $y=x^2-.3$, hence symmetric about the y-axis in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Every circle with radius $r>0$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}^2$.